# Is there a better way to pass class params to an external function?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've created a nodejs module written in typescript that works fine, but I am not particularly happy with the method I've used to pass class declared params to external functions (functions declared outside the class scope). Is there a better way to do this without passing the variables one by one to the 'external' function?

I know I could move the fooFunc function into the class, but I am avoiding this because I do not want this function to be available to the code that consumes the resulting module (I only want check() to be available) due to the class being exported.

```
export class Foo {

   private readonly a: number;

   constructor(a: number) {
      this.a = a;
   }

   async check() {
      fooFunc(this.a);
   }

}

async function fooFunc(a: number) {
   console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `.call` the `fooFunc`, so that `this` inside `fooFunc` refers to the `foo` instance, so there's no need to pass instance variables to `fooFunc`:

```
export class Foo {

   readonly a: number;

   constructor(a: number) {
      this.a = a;
   }

   async check() {
      fooFunc.call(this);
   }

}

async function fooFunc(this: Foo) {
    console.log(this.a);
}
```

(this requires `a` to not be `private`, of course)

Comment: I think this is the most elegant answer as it doesn't add additional complexity to solve the problem, assuming of course that this is also the most performant as performance is key for this module.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a super class that handles this behaviour. Here's my solution

```js
abstract class ParamCheck {
    private readonly args: any[];

    constructor(...args) {
        this.args = args;
    }

    async check() {
        fooFunc(this.args);
    }
}

class Foo extends ParamCheck {
    constructor(private a: number, private b: number) {  
        super(a, b);
    }
}

async function fooFunc(...args) {
    console.log(args);
}

new Foo(1, 2).check();
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could consider composing the foo object by passing an implementation of `fooFunc` into the constructor. [Something like this](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFhAxgawGIFcB2ioF4oAUmAXFJugLYBGEATgJR4B8UAhpiANwBQ3iANqwDOQqKgD24qAG9eUeWFoBLAG6tg0WhFYATcZn4g2pctTo95URavWbteg0cQIUGbKXhI0WRJyhz5RH0hYFp0RGBxWgJWE0oaWgAaKGcvN0QPF29sRllLS2A4JSEAOlY8Ngt8qELiktTXHwqG7N9uSwBfALYhEGwUrIJc9ura0pb0gjGy+iqoLq7uAHoV1aXeYT6cADMfYCV9KG3JSdiyeLphyyDMIXF+CBL+cQBzGNnuRZuQo8kKzAgAHcxJICABGZLHcTpD5Q+qDD5AA):

```
type CheckFunc = (n: number) => any;

export class Foo {

   private readonly a: number;
   private readonly checkFunc: CheckFunc; 

   constructor(a: number, checkFunc: CheckFunc) {
      this.a = a;
      this.checkFunc = checkFunc;
   }

   async check() {
      this.checkFunc(this.a);
   }

}

///////

async function fooFunc(a: number) {
   console.log(a);
}

const foo = new Foo(1, fooFunc);
```

The reason you might want to consider this change is that this function can now safely be unit tested. Depending on a hard coded reference to an external class violates the [Dependency Inversion Principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)